# Creating a printable report showing statistics from Windows Performance Analyzer Xperf

Tags: windows, performance, xperf

This is a very simple question.

I run Xperf and get all statistics about execution of programs, applications, and so on...

Well, I would like to find a tool that enables me to create a printable report of all data collected thank to Xperf.

Xperf, in fact, let me show all data and information regarding disk usage, CPU usage, times, overheads and so on... but does not let me print them... how to do something like this????

Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the xperf command line "actions" described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff190853(v=VS.85).aspx.

I've also read that Microsoft's LogParser can handle ETW input files, but I haven't tried it myself.

Gary Kratkin

Answer (score 0):

The xperf actions are a decent solution, but with WPT 8.1 there is a better option -- wpaexporter.exe. This lets you configure the data to be exported in a more-or-less arbitrary way. See this blog post for details:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/exporting-arbitrary-data-from-xperf-etl-files/